# Trying to get the difference of two different numbers in different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

tenant:

```
roomid monthlypay
12     1000
24     1000
```

utilitypayment:

```
roomid  total
12      500
24      1000
```

```
UPDATE tenant
SET monthlypay=monthlypay-utilitypayment.total
From tenant s inner join utilitypayment i
    on s.roomid=i.roomid WHERE roomid=12
```

I'm trying to get it so whenever i update the bottom one it subtracts onto the first table depending on which room the person wants to update it but when I tried out the code this happens

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Please share the **full and exact** error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL a valid syntax is

```
 UPDATE tenant t 
 INNER JOIN utilitypayment i on t.roomid=i.roomid
    AND t.roomid=12
 SET t.monthlypay=t.monthlypay-i.total
```

or

```
 UPDATE tenant t 
 INNER JOIN utilitypayment i on t.roomid=i.roomid
 SET t.monthlypay=t.monthlypay-i.total
 where t.roomid = 12
```

Comment: thanks it works great on sql but i don't know why when trying to use it on php it doesn't update.

Comment: nevermind it's my fault had to rearrange some things for it to work, thanks again for the help!